# Beacons Not Detected When App ls In Foreground

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, ibeacon

I have an iOS application that detects BLE beacons. The `CLLocationManagerDelegate` methods have been implemented in AppDelegate. Now when the application is in foreground, the `didRangeBeacons` gives an empty beacons array in the logs.

I already have tried explicitly starting ranging in the view controllers, but still does not work.

```swift
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
   ...
   lazy var locationManager: CLLocationManager = {
        let locationManger = CLLocationManager()
        locationManger.delegate = self
        return locationManger
    }()

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        ...
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedAlways {
            locationManager.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion)
            locationManager.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion2)
        }
    }
    ...
}

extension AppDelegate: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
        if beacons.count > 0 {
            print("From Region \(region.identifier)")
        } else {
            print("empty")
        }
}
```

Always prints empty when in foreground.

It should give me the nearest beacons in the region.

The weird thing is when the app is put into background, it immediately detects and shows all the beacons.

Comment: Where do you assign manager's delegate to be AppDelegate?

Comment: When the application is launched.

Comment: Please do show more of your code, especially any lines that manipulate CLLocationManager.  The answer is probably somewhere in this code.

Comment: @davidgyoung those are all the places where I manipulated LocationManager. Also this behavior was observed in iPhone 5, works well in iPhone 6 and above.

Comment: Nowhere in the code shown is there a call to `startRangingBeacons(region: region)`.  I don't see how it could possibly work, even in the background, unless there is other code that is not shown that does start ranging.

Comment: `startRangingBeacons(region: region)` is called in `didEnterRegion`